# How can I perform a bulk delete on issues that have the same status in a project in Jira?

Tags: project-management, jira, agile, scrum, kanban

I have a project called `test_pro` with over 300 issues. Nearly 200 of them have a status *Ready To Release*, and I want to remove all those issues from my project. How can I perform a bulk delete using the status *Ready To Release* and the project name? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was given to me by someone else

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/328291/how-can-i-perform-a-bulk-delete-on-issues-that-have-same-status-in-a-project-jira?page=1#328440

yes it is possible, please read the following steps:

1. Search for the issues with Ready To Release status using JQL query:

   **project = "test_pro" AND status = "Ready To Release"**
2. Tools > Bulk Change > Select All > Delete Issues > Confirm

For more information, please refer the documentation.

Always backup JIRA data before we try, in case we can roll back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the hints from this page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Modifying+Multiple+%28%27Bulk%27%29+Issues ?

Also someone has posted that question on the Atlassian forum, please look here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/191797/how-to-do-bulk-delete-in-jira